# My slider works when it's context specific, but when I try to make it context agnostic it breaks. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's the jQuery I'm dealing with. The `loop()` function works brilliantly when I input the proper id's and such, but now that I've wrapped it in the `Slider()` function, it's broken. I don't know how to fix it. Any help? (jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yramagicman/Uc8LW/8/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function Slider(wrapper, kids) {
    this.wrapper = wrapper;
    this.kids = kids;
this.loop = function(wrapper, kids) {
    var count = $(wrapper).children().length,
        fade = 1000,
        selector = [],
        delay = 1000;
        console.log(count); //logs 0
    for (var i = 1; i < count + 1; i++) {
        selector[i] = $(wrapper + ' ' + kids + ':nth-child(' + i + ')');
                        selector[i].addClass('hidden');
                        console.log(selector[i]);
    }
    var z =1;
    console.log(selector[z]); //logs undefined
    selector[z].each(function () { //uncaught type error
        $(this).addClass('visible').fadeIn(fade).delay(delay).fadeOut(fade, function () {
            $(this).hide().remove().appendTo(wrapper);
        }); //end callback
    });
};
$(wrapper).children().addClass('hidden');
//setInterval(loop, 1000); //commented out for debugging. Don't want a loop doing nothing.
loop();
}
Slider('#slider', 'li');
}); // end ready
```

The related html

```
<ul id="slider">
<li> item 1</li>
<li> item 2</li>
<li> item 3</li>
<li> item 4</li>
</ul>
```

and css

```
.hidden{
position: absolute;
left: -10000px;
top: -10000px;
} 
.visible{
position: static;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle only works for the first iteration. Can you fix it?

Comment: Please fix your jsfiddle

Comment: fiddle repaired. It's supposed to be broken to an extent. I need help making it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Here's the code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var loop = function (wrapper, kids, fade, delay) {
    var count = $(wrapper).children().length,
        selector = [];
    $(wrapper).children().fadeOut(0);
    for (var i = 1; i < count + 1; i++) {
        selector[i] = $(wrapper + ' ' + kids + ':nth-child(' + i + ')');
    }
    var z = 1;
    selector[z].each(function () {
        $(this).fadeIn(fade).delay(delay).fadeOut(fade, function () {
            $(this).remove().appendTo(wrapper);
        }); //end callback

    });

};

setInterval(function () {
    loop('#slider', 'li', 2000, 7000);
}, 0);
});
// end ready
```

All HTML is the same as in the question.